# How do I create a chart(s) in Highcharts where the top gridline of one chart is the bottom gridline of another?

Tags: highcharts

I know this is difficult to describe, so what I'm looking for is in

this picture.

[image: 1]

How do I do this? Is this three separate charts or just one? Please help if you can!

I tried using three different graphs and smooshing them together, but that felt super jenky and is obviously not the correct way to do it. I'm not sure if this is one or three charts in Highcharts or how to get anything that looks like [this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JOP7B.png)

Comment: Do you mean having one chart with three data sets?

Comment: Please include what you have tried in a [mre] - here are some tips on how to improve this question: [ask] - you can also checkout their demo page for inspiration https://www.highcharts.com/demo/spline-symbols

Comment: @blurfus I mean there are 3 datasets, yes, it looks like 3 different charts for the 3 separate data sets that share an x axis, but have 3 different y axis. Like there are technically 4 data sets here in this chart http://jsfiddle.net/ctsLgsv7/2/ , but this isn't what I'm going for. I want it to look like the example I linked above with one dataset in each of the three sections where the sections each use different variables for measuring their Y values, but use the same variable, time in months, to do their Y value.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the code within it in a [mre]

Comment: Have a look at this demo instead: https://www.highcharts.com/demo/combo-multi-axes

Comment: @blurfus I can't edit it right now, because there are too many pending edits, but I did come up with a minimal reproducible example. I'll get to updating as soon as it lets me. Thanks for your help and patience so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a chart with three y-axes and three series. You can use the below options as a base to start.

```
  series: [{
    ...
  }, {
    ...,
    yAxis: 1
  }, {
    ...,
    yAxis: 2
  }],
  yAxis: [{
    height: '33.33%',
    showFirstLabel: false,
    showLastLabel: false
  }, {
    height: '33.33%',
    top: '33.33%',
    offset: 0,
    showFirstLabel: false,
    showLastLabel: false
  }, {
    height: '33.33%',
    top: '66.66%',
    offset: 0,
    showFirstLabel: false,
    showLastLabel: false
  }]
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/vse07qwy/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis

Comment: This is really good and it's almost exactly what I want! The only issue I see is that there are actually two lines really close together where the two axis meet. Look very closely at the gridline where the bottom graph and the second to bottom graph meet. You will see that it is actually two gridlines very close together, and I can't seem to fix this. Would you have any idea? Thanks

Comment: Hi @Andrew Richter, You can disable `startOnTick`, `endOnTick` options and add the horizontal lines in some other way, for example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/4xmg3y0w/

Comment: Thanks! You're good at this. I only know the basics of highcharts. I'll study your solution and try to learn some things.